# Google map invisible when printing with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-chrome, printing

I have read a lot and try a lots of different techniques to manipulate my google map in different way of resizing and everything but none have gave my decent results. The fact simply is that when I hit cmd-p in google Chrome I didn't see my map and the same operation work perfectly in other browsers... I have try many many times to remove all kind of styles possible from my code... I can only conclude that it's a Chrome bug ??

Cmd-p with Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)
[image]

Cmp-p on the same page with Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9)
[image]

I don't think it's relevant here to put all the code that I use to generate driving directions and that stuff...

This just not working in Chrome !?

Thx in advance...

Serge Savoie

Comment: I use bootstrap and Ruby On Rails 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap is overriding some style that should not :

Here is the solution

```
@media print {
  img {
    max-width: none !important;
  }
```